# Overfull \hbox in footnote

Tags: footnotes, warnings, aastex

I'm getting a strange overfull \hbox warning with footnotes when I use the `preprint` style in aastex v6.3.  It's strange because the footnote is *clearly* not overfull despite what the compiler says.  Here's a MWE that shows this in Overleaf:

```
\documentclass[preprint]{aastex63}

\begin{document}

\footnote{Some text to showcase the problem.}

\end{document}
```

The footnote doesn't even cover half the page, yet it still gives a warning.  If I use the `twocolumn` style instead of `preprint`, the warning disappears.  What's the cause of this and how do I fix it?

Comment: If you include the line `\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}` in your preamble and add a long footnote (longer than the text width), then you see that the footnote overshoots the right border by the amount that the footnote label and the separator to the left take. It seems that the footnotes are put into a box of `\textwidth` without subtracting the label. Seems like a bug in the class. If you care enough you could report it to the AAS.

Comment: So it's nothing on my end, and I shouldn't worry about it besides notifying them?

Comment: This is my interpretation ...

Comment: Hi, I work for the AAS Journals. While I don't have an answer we'd like it if you could report this to github (https://github.com/AASJournals/AASTeX60) with an MWE. The preprint/twocolumn test is a very useful bit of information to have.

Comment: @Gus Was this issue ever reported? Because I'm encountering it now and the \hbox warning means I can't submit the paper via Overleaf.

Comment: @cosmosis Yes, you can follow the link above to the Github issue: https://github.com/AASJournals/AASTeX60/issues/127 with workarounds. I didn't know an overfull hbox would stop the submission of a manuscript to our submission portal. I'll pass that on to the right people.